# how to make change in all TreeView's that exist in a form

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, controls

I have some TreeView's in my winform application. I am trying to make mass changes to all of them in one go. So I wrote the code below:

```
private void ResetTreeViewColors()
{
    foreach (TreeView tv in this.Controls)
    {
        foreach(TreeNode tn in tv.Nodes)
        {
            tn.BackColor = Color.White;
            tn.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
}
```

it compiles, but when I call this method, I get an error which says:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeView'.

Well obviously, I have some other controls like buttons and etc... I am wondering that what is wrong with my code that comiples but fails in action!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this.Controls` collection contains all controls, not just treeviews and I'm surprised that doesn't come up with a compile error or even a warning.
You need to check the type of each control before you try and use it as a TreeView:

```
private void ResetTreeViewColors() { 
    foreach (Control tvc in this.Controls) { 
        if (tvc is TreeView) {
            TreeView tv = (TreeView)tvc;
            foreach(TreeNode tn in tv.Nodes) { 
                tn.BackColor = Color.White; 
                tn.ForeColor = Color.Black; 
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: thanks but your code does not compile. It gives `Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeView'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: Errr is here `TreeView tv = tvc;`  the tvc has something wrong :P

Comment: Sorry, as the error said, it was missing a cast. I've added it now.

Answer (score 1):

There are also controls in your forms that are not of type TreeView, and therefore cannot be cast as one. Try this:

```
foreach (control c in this.Controls)
{
  TreeView tr = c as TreeView;
  if(tr != null)
    // your logic here
}
```

Comment: That suffers from exactly the same problem as the OP in that it doesn't actually check of the control IS a TreeView before trying to use it as such.

Comment: The `as TreeView` combined with `tr != null` performs the check.

Comment: I did it like this but for some reason it does not do anything! `            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
              TreeView tr = c as TreeView;
              if (tr != null)
              {
                  foreach (TreeNode tn in tr.Nodes)
                  {
                      tn.BackColor = Color.White;
                      tn.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                  }
              }
            }`

Comment: You need to provide more information beyond "it does not do anything." For example, when you inspect each `c` in the debugger, what are they?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of that behaviour on C# > 2.0. I will remove my downvote if the answer is edited.

Comment: @Deanna, Are you aware of what the `as` operator does? Or perhaps I'm not.

Comment: @AtoMerZ: No I wasn't, it's not part of C# 2.0 that I use as I noted above.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that it can be a nested controls within a form and nested nodes within a treeView root nodes. So the final code should looks like this:

```
ResetChildTreeViews(this); // reset all treeviews within a form
//...
static void ResetChildTreeViews(Control container) {
    foreach(Control ctrl in container.Controls) {
        if(ctrl is TreeView)
            ResetTreeViewColors(ctrl as TreeView);
        else ResetChildTreeViews(ctrl);
    }
}
static void ResetTreeViewColors(TreeView treeView) {
    foreach(TreeNode node in treeView.Nodes)
        ResetTreeNodeColors(node);
}
static void ResetTreeNodeColors(TreeNode node) {
    node.BackColor = Color.White;
    node.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    foreach(TreeNode childNode in node.Nodes) 
        ResetTreeNodeColors(childNode);
}
```